# Can a MySQL database be recovered from just the data directory (and no SQL backups)?

Tags: mysql, wamp

My PC crashed and I lost my WAMP files. Although I have a copy, I do not know how to retrieve the database. Can I copy the WAMP files to another system and then access phpMyAdmin or something? I think it's not possible.

Any other ways where I could do so? I have tried re-installing. But I have no idea how to retrieve them. All I have is just a copy of the WAMP server folder.

Comment: do you have something like this directory `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data`? in your wamp server folder...

Comment: You probably can restore, as long as there is no file corruption also. Back up those files in a safe place, and then reinstall **the same version** of MySQL to a computer. You can then stop the MySQL server, move the default data folders out of the way, copy the old ones in, and try bringing the server back up.

Answer (score -1):

You can make dump for necessary databases

Open CMD and type

[Replace brackets and information inside with your parameters]

```
\wamp\bin\mysql\{mysql5.5.24}\bin\mysqldump.exe -u {root} -p{} {dbname} > \Users\{username}\Desktop\dump.sql
```

The opposite action its:

```
\wamp\bin\mysql\{mysql5.5.24}\bin\mysql.exe -u {root} -p{} {dbname} < \Users\{username}\Desktop\dump.sql
```